# How to schedule a one-time Background App Refresh task in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In iOS, we can use [Updating Your App with Background App Refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) and  **setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval** to setup a periodic background App Refresh task (even though the periodic refresh is not guaranteed).

Similarly, can we setup **one-time** background app refresh task **programmatically** that is scheduled to run **in future** ?

The logic I am trying to implement is :

```
if( action_happened AND no_network_connectivity) {
    // 1) add action to a local storage

    // 2) create a future background job that'll 
            - wake up even when app is in background
            - read all such queued up actions from local storage
            - re-apply those actions

    // 3) when background job runs, if network connectivity is still bad, then the 
job should setup a new one time job in future

}
```

Comment: No.  You can just use background fetch and  do nothing if you have nothing to upload

Comment: But I do not want to run the background fetch if there is no need to do it, setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval will make it recurring. For my usecase, 99% of time it'll wake up and do nothing. I am aware OS will monitor and adjust the frequency. But the BEST way for my usecase is a one-time task. Thoughts ?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS to send your data?  If so then you might be able to just use a background `URLSession`

Comment: Yes it is https. Will that work if when the app goes to background (after action is triggered) ? If so, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you can put all of your data into one HTTP transfer you can create a background URLSession and just fire it off.  iOS performs the transfer when it can outside of your process and gives you delegate callbacks.  Check out [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/709/) for an overview.